# Show that if $(1+x)^n=a_{0}+a_{1}x +a_{2}x^2+ \cdots + a_{n}x^n$ then $(a_{0}-a_{2}+a_{4}-\cdots )^2+(a_{1}-a_{3}+\cdots )^2=a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

***We know that*** $$(1+x)^n=1+\binom{n}{1}x+\binom{n}{2}x^2+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}x^n$$

***So we have to solve for*** $$\left(1-\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}-\cdots\right)^2+
\left(\binom{n}{1}-\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{5}-\cdots\right)^2=1+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots$$

Comment: There are errors in the title.

Comment: Your title is a mess. Did you mean $(1+x)^n?$ Did you mean $a_nx^n?$ Is there a reason to represent it in terms of $a_i$ rather than $\binom ni?$

Comment: I also am very confused by the question.  Since $(1 + x)^2 = 1 + 2x + x^2$, I have difficulty not assuming that $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 2, a_2 = 1,$ and for $k \geq 3,$ you must have that $a_k = 0$.  What am I missing?

Comment: Correct the title in the question. I think it's $(1+x)^n$.

Comment: I have fixed all the errors in the question. Thanks @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f(x) = (1+x)^n$.

Consider $$g(x) = \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2 = 1+\binom{n}2 x^2 + \binom{n}4 x^4 + \cdots$$

Now we evaluate it at $x= {\rm i}$ (imaginary unit)
$$
g({\rm i}) =1-\binom{n}2 + \binom{n}4  - \cdots
$$

Similarly define
$$h(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2 =  \binom{n}1 x + \binom{n}3 x^3 + \cdots
$$

Now evaluate it at $x= {\rm i}$ and divide by $\rm i$:
$$
h({\rm i})/{\rm i} = \binom{n}1  - \binom{n}3 + \cdots .
$$

You are interested in finding
$$
[g({\rm i})]^2 + [h({\rm i})/{\rm i}]^2 = \frac{\left[(1+{\rm i})^n + (1-{\rm i})^n \right]^2}4 - 
\frac{\left[(1+{\rm i})^n - (1-{\rm i})^n \right]^2}4.
$$
We use the difference of squares formula (twice) and obtain:
$$
(1-{\rm i})^{n} (1+{\rm i})^{n} =(1-{\rm i}^2)^{n}  = 2^n = f(1).
$$
This proves your equality.

Comment: Or just put $x=i$ in the binomial expansion.